# Rest architecture for multi-language, multi-role native apps

Tags: rest, multilingual, nativeapplication

we are developing a native app running on different mobile OS with extensive functionality. We have to provide multi language and multi user role scenarios. As backend we have to use REST Services with XML based data exchange.
We are planing to implement a 'appInit' REST call after log-in to provide the UI with the valid menu items and all UI texts respecting the role of the current user. The server side stored user profile contains the user language so we are able to choose the correct language instead of OS language.
Is this a acceptable practice?
thx.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the actual API isn't localized, you're good.

I am guessing that you plan to expose a rest endpoint that returns an xml document with the localized info. That would work fine, and be restful.

One thing you would really want to consider, if the localization resource is large is to provide an etag for it (or antother hash), so you only download this info when it has become outdated.